# Get a server method result before executing a Collection transform

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

Working on [CoinsManager](http://www.coinsmanager.com/), I have a model directory with a class per file, and I want to read and list all those files in my collection transform method, to initialize my doc with the correct class.

**server/methods.coffee**:

```coffee
Meteor.methods
  implemented_coins: ->
    """
    Returns a list of coins that have been implemented
    """
    files = fs.readdirSync './app/models/cryptos/'
    file.replace(".coffee.js", "") for file in files.filter (file) ->
      file.search("(base_crypto*)|(js.map)") == -1
```

**collections/addresses.coffee**:

```coffee
if Meteor.isReady
  @implementedCoins = Meteor.call "implemented_coins"

@Addresses = new Meteor.Collection "addresses",
  transform: (doc) ->
    # Retrieve class from code, and pass it the address
    if doc.code in @implementedCoins
      new @[doc.code] doc.address
    else doc
```

**client/views/addresses/addresses_list.coffee**

```coffee
Template.userAddresses.helpers
  userAddresses: ->
    addresses = Addresses.find
      userId: Meteor.user()._id
    address.set_balance() for address in addresses
    return addresses
```

Right now, I'm getting the following error on the client console:

```
Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined
    at indexOf (native)
    at Addresses.Meteor.Collection.transform
```

Which means that in my collection transform, the `@implementedCoins` variable is undefined, because I didn't implement it correctly.

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is wrong:

```
if Meteor.isReady
  @implementedCoins = Meteor.call "implemented_coins"
```

I don't think there is a field in `Meteor` with that name, and even if it was, then it would get executed on startup, but at that time `isReady` is probably false and so your variable doesn't get set. Did you mean `Meteor.startup`? Secondly, on the client you need to use a callback for `call`, since there are no fibers on the client.

Would this work instead?

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.call("implemented_coins", function(err, res) { 
         implementedCoins = res; 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer :) yes, it seems to work with your method (other bug to fix, but it doesn't seem related).
I'm a bit confused as to why the callback is called before the address transform, can you explain it ?

Comment: not sure, but it's probably to do with the collection not being `ready` yet. It will actually be called initially on page load, but at that time the collection is empty and so the transform doesn't apply. It is then re-run when the collection is synced to the client.